# While using a JAXB parser i have a file which has several objects(or entities) with same name. So how to get different objects for each entity?

Tags: java, jaxb

**A sample file would be**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customers>
<customer id="100">
    <age>29</age>
    <name>rohit</name>
</customer>
<customer id="10">
    <age>29</age>
    <name>acharya</name>
</customer>
</customers>
```

**I want to create two POJO objects of customer. So how do i do it using JAXB parser.

Comment: What is the problem ? You ask to provide the whole code ? Have you read tutorials on JAXB ? This seems to be a basic thing.

Comment: If you had tried to write a minimal XML:Schema and compiled it with JAXB, you had the answer (JAXB generates some list or array type for such case)

Comment: Not the whole code. Some idea on how to iterate to the second customer  tag values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following wrapper class to unmarshal the XML document as a `List` of `Customer` objects.  Then use the `List` APIs to iterate to the second instance of `Customer`.

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Customers {

    private List<Customer> customers;

    @XmlElement(name="customer")
    private List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        return customers;
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html